# What is the point of the BusyBox docker image?

Tags: docker, busybox

I thought I understood Docker. I understood it as a way to package up software with lots of dependencies..to basically create a little world where absolutely everything is taken care of for a piece of software. Then I stumbled upon this on DockerHub

https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/

It's an image for BusyBox, which is a tiny little Linux binary that is meant for embedded systems. Then the top comment says:

> Busybox is awesome :) By far the most useful container per byte on the entire registry.

But I don't understand at all why this image exists, which makes me think that I don't actually understand why Docker exists. What is the point of a BusyBox docker image?

Comment: If you think people only create useful things, and that they never use sarcasm in describing the things they create...

Comment: busybox container is a Swiss-army knife that helps you diagnose docker network

Comment: I favourited this question on the title alone :)

Answer (score 49):

A Busybox docker image is useful if one is building a container for which busybox can fulfill its dependency chain without needing a full Linux distro.

Often, an embedded appliance can consist of nothing but a statically-linked copy of busybox, an init script that mounts procfs, sysfs, &c. with busybox-provided tools, and then the actual application being invoked. With docker setting up the filesystem namespace, even that init script isn't necessarily needed.

Comment: I see. So there are some deep things I don't understand about Docker. Are you saying that you use the busybox image as part of another larger docker image?

Comment: Just about *all* your public docker images are intended to be used as a base.

Comment: Alright then, thanks. I'll look into what that means.

Comment: ...so, you take the public Debian X.Y image, tell Docker you want to add an extra file to it / install a package onto it / bind-mount something from the host into it, and then that's your actual application container.

Comment: ...here, you just have something much lighter and thinner than a Debian/Ubuntu/CentOS/etc. base.

Comment: Oh, duh. This is obvious in hindsight. You're talking about saying "FROM busybox" instead of from a fatter Linux distribution. That makes tons of sense. I dun got confused...

Comment: Yup, exactly. Though I wouldn't be surprised if the actual use case for this one wasn't more about just letting people test busybox quickly (ie. to determine functionality that is/isn't supported in a release compiled with all options enabled) without needing to install much anything on their host.

Comment: I've just used the busybox Docker image in a production environment, in a way that even using the Debian image would be harder to use.

I just wanted to fetch a file using `wget` and `unzip` it. Not only both tools come pre-installed, but the `unzip` from busybox accepts zip files from stdin. The `unzip` from Debian doesn't.

busybox is just a builder, where it starts with `FROM busybox as build` and the actual image just copies the unzipped file with `COPY --from=build`.

Other than that, as someone pointed out, you can just use the tools in a Docker network, with no setup required.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hi it is 2021 but I still don't understand the use case of busybox, can you like at my question here ? Thank! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529042/what-is-the-difference-between-alpine-docker-image-and-busybox-docker-image

Answer (score 21):

In addition to being a convenient base to use for other docker images. Busybox also makes a very convenient `initContainer` for kubernetes: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

Say you need something to happen that sets up the pod filesystem before your *real* container starts running then busybox is great at this..

As a concrete example the official `redis` image doesn't run redis as *root* and so it cannot access the filesystem. If you were running redis with disk backup (in `appendonly` mode for example) you would need to open up that disk permission for it.

a valid (though probably hacky) initContainer for a statefulSet of redis might looks something like so:

```
      initContainers:
      - name: redis-data-permission-fix
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/chmod", "-R", "777", "/opt/data/redis"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /opt/data/redis
```

Comment: But why not use alpine ?

Comment: In this example no reason I guess. They'd both be fine for this

Comment: I asked a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529042/what-is-the-difference-between-alpine-docker-image-and-busybox-docker-image

Answer (score 6):

> But I don't understand at all why this image exists, which makes me think that I don't actually understand why Docker exists. What is the point of a BusyBox docker image?

I just started using BusyBox with docker, but so far it has been convenient to use with the  **--rm** command to *create unsaved* instances with common built in utilities like **ping**, and yeah just ping so far :/

```
docker container run --rm -it --network [network_name] busybox
```

and then all those utilities in BusyBox are available on that docker custom network and instantly destroyed when you **exit** the BusyBox CLI