# Why there is no logon happens when attach to docker busybox image?

Tags: docker

```
$ docker run --rm -it busybox
/ # who
<empty>
```

In the next session I'm trying to attach to this docker container and expecting second user will appear, but no luck again:

```
$ docker attach `docker container ls | grep busybox | cut -d" " -f1`
/ # who
<empty again>
```

So the question is - why there are no logons happened not by first run-and-attach, not by consequent attaches? And why there is no even a single logon into this container?

Comment: Is it so for specific container only - busybox?

Comment: I mentioned busybox only for example, this situation keeps on Ubuntu images too. You can try: `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.10` then type `who`

Comment: The answer of Alexander now seems more to the point than, if you run docker on Linux, but that answer is not marked as accepted yet, so... Are you on Linux? Do you think the reason could be OS specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`who` reads the list of users from `/var/run/utmp`. On a regular Linux system, the `login` program prompts for the username and password and then starts the user's shell. It also updates `/var/run/utmp` with the new user.
The same thing happens for SSH and Telnet servers. They are expected to update `/var/run/utmp`.

In a Docker container, `login` is usually not executed. Docker isolates resources from the host system with [Linux Namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces), it does not provide a complete Linux system. When you enter a Docker container, the given entrypoint or command is executed with PID 1.
Subsequent `docker exec` calls are handled in a similar way. Docker enters the namespace of the container and executes the given command.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: after some reading I see Alexander answer as more to the point. Couple of useful links I've read along that way:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/

https://lwn.net/Articles/531114

---

As far as I understand busybox docker container is very basic and does not support all functionality of full-fledged Linux.

Here [I thought I understood Docker until I saw the BusyBox docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291458/i-thought-i-understood-docker-until-i-saw-the-busybox-docker-image) there is a discussion about what that image is and what it is for.

Comment: It's not specific to BusyBox. The same thing happens for the Ubuntu, Debian and Arch images (and possibly most other images).